# Do you need a User Access token to access the facebook graph people search?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to do it with an App access token? I want to make an app that has a lot to do with anonymity so I don't want to have to run the user through facebook login if I don't have to. Is a user access token the only way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It used to be possible to do a search with no token, but it seems like you now have to use a user token.  I've tried with an app access token and it just returns an error saying a user access token is needed.